# invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)

Tags: c, struct

I know it's not the first thread with this error but I really can't get what's wrong... My code is bellow:

```
/* File descriptor sets */
struct descs {
    fd_set read;
    fd_set write;
    fd_set except;
};

typedef struct descs descs_t;

/* Server representation */
struct server {
    int                 sock;                   /* Server sock descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in  addr;                   /* Server address */
    socklen_t           addrlen;                /* Server address size */
    char                buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];    /* Message buffer */
    int                 len;                    /* Message buffer length */
};

typedef struct server server_t;

void build_fds(struct server *srv, struct descs *fd) {
    FD_ZERO(fd->read);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, fd->read);
    FD_SET(srv->sock, fd->read);

    FD_ZERO(fd->write);
    // there is smth to send, set up write_fd for server socket
    if (srv->len > 0) {
        FD_SET(srv->sock, fd->write);
    }

    FD_ZERO(fd->except);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, fd->except);
    FD_SET(srv->sock, fd->except);
}
```

I am passing my struct via pointer so I must use `->` but it crashes with errors:

```
chatcl.c: In function ‘build_fds’:
chatcl.c:37: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:38: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:39: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:41: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:44: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:47: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:48: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
chatcl.c:49: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘fd_set’)
make: *** [chatcl] Error 1
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `&`, i.e. you need the address of the data structure, e.g.

```
#include <sys/select.h>

struct descs {
  fd_set a;
};

void func(struct descs *d) {
  FD_ZERO(&d->a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about it even.

Answer (score 2):

From [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) the FD_* macros they take pointers to `fd_set`:

```
   void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
   int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
   void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
   void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

You should pass pointers to the functions (macros), not values. You can use the [address-of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of) operator:

```
FD_ZERO(&fd->read);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fd->read);
FD_SET(srv->sock, &fd->read);
```

and so on.